# Setting next LaunchScreen during runtime

Tags: ios, splash-screen, launch-screen

In my app the background color can be changed. Currently the LaunchScreen is just white and changes to the background color once the app has loaded. Is there any way that I can change the color that the LaunchScreen is going to have the next time the app starts. I know there is no way to run code while in the LaunchScreen, but maybe its image can be changed during runtime.

Comment: Nope, can't be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment, it is impossible.